# Cannot read property 'next' of undefined. Angular. Error on renaming

Tags: angular

I have an Angular service which sends data using socket and reads an answer then sends that answer to subscribers:

```
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { DocumentService } from "./document.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { SignatureRequest } from "../models/signature-request";
import { SignatureResponse } from "../models/signature-response";

@Injectable()
export class SignatureService {
    private socket;
    private response: Subject<SignatureResponse>;

    constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
        this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:13337/sign");

        this.socket.onmessage = this.onResponse;
    }

    onResponse(response) {
        let signatureResponse: SignatureResponse = JSON.parse(response.data);

        this.response.next(signatureResponse);
    }

    sign(pdfDocument: string, pin: string, duties: string, stampNumber: string): Observable<SignatureResponse> {
        let signatureRequest = new SignatureRequest();
        signatureRequest.PdfBase64 = pdfDocument;
        signatureRequest.Pin = pin;
        signatureRequest.Duties = duties;
        signatureRequest.StampNumber = stampNumber;

        this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(signatureRequest));

        this.response = new Subject<SignatureResponse>();
        this.socket.response = this.response;
        return this.response.asObservable();
    }
}
```

I had to make some renaming and ended up with service that is almost identical, just some names changed. As you can see most 'response' => 'signResponse' and 'request' => 'signRequest':

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { DocumentService } from "./document.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { SignatureSignRequest } from "../models/signature-sign-request";
import { SignatureSignResponse } from "../models/signature-sign-response";

@Injectable()
export class SignatureService {
    private signSocket;
    private signResponse: Subject<SignatureSignResponse>;

    constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
        this.signSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:13337/sign");

        this.signSocket.onmessage = this.onSignResponse;
    }

    onSignResponse(response) {
        let signatureSignResponse: SignatureSignResponse = JSON.parse(response.data);

        this.signResponse.next(signatureSignResponse);
    }

    sign(pdfDocument: string, pin: string, duties: string, stampNumber: string): Observable<SignatureSignResponse> {
        let signatureRequest = new SignatureSignRequest();
        signatureRequest.PdfBase64 = pdfDocument;
        signatureRequest.Pin = pin;
        signatureRequest.Duties = duties;
        signatureRequest.StampNumber = stampNumber;

        this.signSocket.send(JSON.stringify(signatureRequest));

        this.signResponse = new Subject<SignatureSignResponse>();
        this.signSocket.response = this.signResponse;
        return this.signResponse.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Version 1 works great. But after renaming i am getting

> Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

error. Which occurs when

> this.signResponse.next(signatureSignResponse);

is reached. I am getting an answer thru socket in both versions but in second version I am getting error and data isn't delivered to my subscribers. Does anyone have a clue what went wrong? Maybe I missed something important to include or rename in other parts of setup. Please ask for additional info if you need it since I am not familiar with angular and not sure what is needed to identify an error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because constructor called before the sign function where you declare the new instance to the `signResponse`. Declare the instance inside the construcor

```
constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
    this.signSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:13337/sign");
    this.signResponse = new Subject<SignatureSignResponse>();

    this.signSocket.onmessage = this.onSignResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it doesn't seem to be working. Nothing changed. In addition it doesn't explain why in version 1 it works without declaring instance inside constructor.